# Update Commerce Cart using Ajax

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ajax, javascript

Is there a way to update the cart using ajax?

I've tried something like:

```
$('span.quick-cart-add>p>a').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var data                    = {};
    data["purchasableId"]       = $(this).data("id");
    data["qty"]                 = $(this).data("qty");
    data[window.csrfTokenName]  = window.csrfTokenValue;


    $.post( "/actions/commerce/cart/updateCart", data, function(response) {

        alert( "success" );

    }).always(function(response) { console.log(data, response); });

});
```

I've tried passing `"lineItemId"` instead of `"purchasableId"`, and also sending to `"/actions/commerce/cart/updateLineItem"`, they all return `response.success` but the cart is never actually updated.

Am I not sending the right amount of fields/values, or is there something I'm missing when trying to accomplish this via ajax?

Comment: I'm trying to implement the above but not getting a response. My cart seems to updating ok via ajax, but I'd like the 'Success' message to execute so I can build out the next part of the script. $(function() { $form = $("#addToCartForm"); // handle submits via ajax $form.on('submit', function(e) { //Prevent the default submission e.preventDefault(); //Get the form data var form_data = $form.serializeArray(); // ajax it over to the server $.ajax({ type: 'post', url: '/', data: form_data, success: function(response) { if (response.success) { alert("Success"); } else { alert("Failure!"); } } });

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do all the normal commerce actions via ajax.

How this is done changed slightly with Craft 4/Commerce 4, so use the appropriate approach below.  (Basically, they used to use an attribute on the response (`response.success`) - but now the use response codes instead to determine success/failure).

A basic recipe is this...

HTML:

```
        <form method="POST" id="addToCartForm">
        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="purchasableId" value="{{ product.id }}">
        <input type="number" name="qty">
        </form>
```

JS (Craft/Commerce 4, and presumably later...):

```
        $form = ("#addToCartForm");
        var form_data = $form.serializeArray()
        form_data.push({
            name: window.csrfTokenName,
            value: window.csrfTokenValue
        })

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: action,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,

            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {                  
                if (jqXHR.status === 200){
                     // Handle success...
                }
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                // Handle failure
            }
```

JS (up to Craft/Commerce 3):

```
        $form = ("#addToCartForm");
        var form_data = $form.serializeArray()
        form_data.push({
            name: window.csrfTokenName,
            value: window.csrfTokenValue
        })

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    // handle success
                }
                else {
                    // handle failure
                }
            }
```

....response.cart will have the updated cart in it.