# Update Craft Commerce cart with ajax

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ajax, cart

Have been trying to get cart updates via ajax.

I've looked at this answer:
'https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/update-commerce-cart-using-ajax'

My cart seem to update ok but I can't seem to get an alert to confirm it which will prevent me from adding post-submission messaging etc.

My code so far is:

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="addToCartForm"  class="voucher-purchase needs-validation" novalidate >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
                                <input type="hidden" name="purchasableId" value="{{ voucher.purchasableId }}">
                                {{ actionInput('commerce/cart/update-cart') }}
                                {{ csrfInput() }}

                                <input type="hidden" type="number" name="qty" value="1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>TO:</label>
                                    <p>Please enter the name of the voucher recipient.</p>
                                    <input id="validationCustom01" class="form-control py-3" type="text" name="options[to]" placeholder="Recipient's Name" required >
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter recipient name.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>FROM:</label>
                                    <p>Please enter who is gifting the voucher.</p>
                                    <input class="form-control py-3"  type="text" name="options[from]" placeholder="Your Name" required > 
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your name.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>MESSAGE: (Optional):</label>
                                    <p>Please enter a personalised message to the voucher recipient.</p>
                                    <textarea class="form-control py-3" rows="8" name="options[message]" placeholder="Enter your personalised message..."></textarea>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a message to include with the voucher.</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {% if voucher.customAmount %}
                                    <label>AMOUNT:</label>
                                    <p>Please nominate the value of the voucher.</p>
                                    <div class="amount afterWrap">
                                        <input class="voucherValue form-control" required  type="number" name="options[amount]" placeholder="Amount" step="25">
                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please specify a value</div>
                                    </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group mt-5">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="add-to-cart button btn btn-black">
                                    <input id="addToCart" type="submit" value="Checkout" class="button btn btn-black">
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

JS

```
   $(function() {
$form = $("#addToCartForm");
// handle submits via ajax
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    //Prevent the default submission
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the form data
    var form_data = $form.serializeArray();
    // ajax it over to the server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                alert('Success');
            }
            else {
                alert('Failure!');
            }
        }
    });        
});
```

});

Has anyone been able to achieve update cart via ajax with something like the above?

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for perhaps answering a substitute question but it seems to me as though what you really need to know is how to do basic debugging in JavaScript, since it only requires a quick bit of `console.log()` to see why your conditional check is failing:

To debug your code, examine the response object by putting `console.log(response)` in your success function, and then submitting the form with your inspector's console tab open. You'll notice that, in Commerce 4 at least, the response object does not include any such property called `success`, only `cart`, `message`, `modelName` and `redirect`:

[image]

You could check the `message` property for the exact string "Cart updated.", but that seems a bit fragile to me (especially if your site could potentially be translated in future). There's a better way - if you force a deliberate error, you'll notice that the error response object contains some useful properties, any of which could be used in a conditional check: `error`, `exception` and `status`. So for example you could check whether `response.error` is empty. Equally, you could check for the absence of the `cart` object.

Comment: Got me on the right track - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour with ajax responses changed significantly with Craft 4 / Commerce 4 - I have updated my answer to that original question: [Update Commerce Cart using Ajax](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/update-commerce-cart-using-ajax)

...to cover both scenarios.

Comment: Awesome - thank you!!